# Why is the option to add to a changelist missing from my TortoiseSVN window?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I want to move these files to a changelist I have for autogenerated files.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

But as you can see the option doesn't exist. Additionally, anytime that I try to simply add them to an ignore list, I get an error stating that this isn't possible.

---

[image]

---

I've already added similar files to this changelist as you can see.

---

[image]

---

Any ideas why in the commit window I can't do this for some files? I'm happy to provide more information if necessary.

---

I've done an SVN cleaup with these options to no avail.

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because those files are not files, they are directories. The [changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.changelists.html#svn.advanced.changelists.limitations) feature only works for files:

> **Changelist Limitations**
>
> Subversion's changelist feature is a handy tool for grouping working
>   copy files, but it does have a few limitations. Changelists are
>   artifacts of a particular working copy, which means that changelist
>   assignments cannot be propagated to the repository or otherwise shared
>   with other users. **Changelists can be assigned only to files—Subversion
>   doesn't currently support the use of changelists with directories.**
>   Finally, you can have at most one changelist assignment on a given
>   working copy file. Here is where the blog post category and photo
>   service tag analogies break down—if you find yourself needing to
>   assign a file to multiple changelists, you're out of luck.

If I understand your ultimate goal, you need the `svn:ignore` property in parent directory.

- To ignore `App_Data`, set `svn:ignore` to `App_Data` for root folder.
- To ignore `cache`, set `svn:ignore` to `cache` for `App_Data`.